# NotFoundHttpException is not catched in controller with Lumen 5.6

Tags: laravel, exception, lumen

I want to manage 404 error with a custom json response.

Here is the code:

```
try {
            $registration = Registration::find($id);
            if ($registration == null) throw new NotFoundHttpException();
            return response()->json($registration, HttpResponse::HTTP_OK);
        } catch (NotFoundHttpException $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Registration not found'], HttpResponse::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
```

but it nevers enter in the catch block, and return a HTML view :

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
in RoutesRequests.php line 226
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array(0))
in RoutesRequests.php line 164
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}()
in RoutesRequests.php line 413
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure))
in RoutesRequests.php line 166
at Application->dispatch(null)
in RoutesRequests.php line 107
at Application->run()
in index.php line 28
at require('/Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/jaumo/public/index.php')
in server.php line 147
```

I also tried with `Registration::findOrFail($id);` which is supposed to return 40 error, but it is the same result

I could change it in `Handler.php` :

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            return response()->json('Not Found', HttpResponse::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

but this is not quite what I want, here the message is static, I would like to manage it in controller.

I also tried to add `NotFoundHttpException::class` to $dontReport array, but it is not working

Why, and how can I do just to return a custom json response.

Comment: Did you remember to import the namespaced exception at the top?

Comment: do you mean: `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;` ??? in this case yes !

Answer (score 0):

I found my error, it was a 404 on the route, I had:

```
$router->get('/registrations/{id}', 'RegistrationController@show');
```

instead of

```
$router->get('/registration/{id}', 'RegistrationController@show');
```

so, it never enter the controller, that is why it was not cathing my exception.

Thanks for your help!